# How to check if variable matches, then do something

Tags: python, diff, difference

I have a script that pulls some data from a network device, strips off some crap and returns a value via a re.search.

the end result is i have two variables that contain a numerical value, say file1 contains one line with '10', file2 contains one line with '20'. i've put these into variables

```
oldnumber = 10
newnumber = 20
```

what i need to do is check to see if the numbers are the same value. if the numbers are the same, do nothing. if they aren't the same, then do something else - ie. send a mail to myself (smtplib works for me).

i'm new to python and finding my way, not sure how to code this?

i suppose the simplest way to describe this is if oldnumber = newnumber, then send mail, else do nothing.

Comment: `oldnumber == newnumber` (equality test not assignment) but otherwise: yes, that's exactly what you would do. If you don't know how to write it, read [a tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements).

Comment: @captain yossarian please read the docs carefully its simple

Comment: thanks for that. easier than i thought!

Answer (score 1):

If I remember well you're right
just do

```
if oldnumber!=newnumber;
   do what you want
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm

Answer (score 1):

almost right.

```
if oldnumber != newnumber: 
    # do something

# and then proceed..
```

Or:

```
if oldnumber == newnumber: 
    # do this
else:
    # do that

# and then proceed..
```